# How to fire on Mouse Button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, projectile

I'm trying to do my first platformer at Unity. And have some problem with projectile. I found a tutorial, how create a projectile moving, but without trigger on Fire button. It is possible to change this script for firing on button? I tried to make it with if statement, but then projectile move only ones, it doesn't fly :(

```
public class projectile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject target;

    private float playerX;
    private float targetX;

    private float dist;
    private float nextX;
    private float baseY;
    private float height;

    public float speed = 10f; 


    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy");
    }

    void Update()
    {  
       Fire();           
    }

    public static Quaternion LookAtTarget(Vector2 rotation)
    {
        return Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Mathf.Atan2(rotation.y, rotation.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg); 
    }

    private void Fire()
    {       
        playerX = player.transform.position.x;
        targetX = target.transform.position.x;

        dist = targetX - playerX;
        nextX = Mathf.MoveTowards(transform.position.x, targetX, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        baseY = Mathf.Lerp(player.transform.position.y, target.transform.position.y, (nextX - playerX) / dist);
        height = 2 * (nextX - playerX) * (nextX - targetX) / (-0.25f * dist * dist);

        Vector3 movePosition = new Vector3(nextX, baseY + height, transform.position.z);
        transform.rotation = LookAtTarget(movePosition - transform.position);

        if (transform.position == target.transform.position)
        {
              Destroy(gameObject);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's in the `Update` method happens every frame, so you need to create a manual trigger (`bool isFired`).

The idea is that when `isFired` is false, nothing happens.
Then, when `isFired` turns to true, the projectile starts moving.

Your `Fire` method actually makes the projectile move so you should rename it to `Move` and in `Update` you call `Move` only when the projectile is fired.

```
public class projectile : MonoBehaviour
{
    // At the start, the projectile is not fired
    bool isFired = false;

    void Update()
    {
        // If the player presses a button, the projectile is fired
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) isFired = true;
        // Only if the projectile is fired, it should moves
        if (isFired) Move();
    }

    void Move()
    {
        // Here you have the content of your Fire method
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually ... I would rather have the projectile move **always** .. but only **spawn** one when hitting the button .. that's at least how you would do this usually

Comment: Usually I would do that too but for a beginner I felt understanding the logic was more valuable than knowing the best architecture, correct casing and possible optimizations that can be applied to this script